# Better way to fetch data and update from firebase with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a World Cup Betting App. It has 64 matches, each one with your away_score and home_score, like this:

```
matches: {
    1: {
      name: 1,
      type: "group",
      home_team: 1,
      away_team: 2,
      home_result: ' ',
      away_result: ' ',
      date: "2018-06-14T18:00:00+03:00",
      stadium: 1,
      channels: [],
      finished: false,
      group: "a"
    },
    2: {...
```

I have an entity called MatchesBuilder, that fetch the data from the firebase and set the state. This is state is passed as props for a entity called GroupsBuilder, who has a List of Matches. Every time a user updates his bet for the match, it updates the values on the firebase.

```
 fetchMatches = async () => {
    const { firebaseApp, user } = this.props;
    await firebaseApp
      .database()
      .ref(`/pools/${this.props.pool.key}/users/${user.uid}/matches`)
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        this.setState({
          matches: this.snapshotToArray(snapshot),
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
    await this.checkBettingStatus();
  };
```

And on my Match entity I have:

```
<TextField id={`${this.props.game.home_team}_home`}
type="number"
disabled={this.props.finishedTimeToBet}
value={this.props.game.home_result}
onChange={(e, game, type) =>
this.props.handleChangedResult(e, this.props.game, "home")
}
/>
```

It is working. But just because, I have a method that updates the state on the MatchesBuilder (it reloads all the data every time a user changes a value on the input) and pass as props again.

So everytime I update something on my Textfield, it calls a function and fetches again the data from firebase. Of course Im having performance issues.

What is your suggestion for a better and with better performance for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got what you are saying correctly, but what about using 'on' instead of 'once'? That way the state should change whenever that node in the database does.

Comment: Exactly Barazu. I guessed when I put it here. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a submit button so that you are only ever updating your app when a user saves a bet? That would bring down the network requests substantially. Without any idea of what your view looks like it's hard to say if this is suitable but I think the general goal is to trigger only one network request per edit as binding a network request to an onChange handler seems excessive.

I'm sure you're able to code it, simply wrap your textfield in a form, add a button and use the onSubmit event of your form to send the network request.